# python freeopcua data : array element access

Tags: python, opc-ua

I am trying to use FreeOpcUa as a test client for a signed and encrypted connection to a server. This setup is running well and I can access existing nodes (get_value). My server provides test data as an array, but I can't access data for writing (set_value). I have checked the examples and searched the net but haven't found a solution until now. Should look like this:

```
...

var = client.get_node(ua.NodeId(.., ..))

data = var.get_value()

for x in range (32):

    ...

    var.set_value(data[x])

...
```

I'm no expert in python so my question: can anyone show me an example how to get this working? I know that I have to take care for rank and array dimensions but don't know how to handle this. Thanks!...

## Python part:

```
    #set node value
    print("Data will be read ...")
    var = client.get_node(ua.NodeId(3, 4))
    data = var.get_value()

    print(data)
    for x in range (32):
        data[x] = x

    print("Data will be set ...")
    var.set_value(data)
    print(var.get_value())
```

## Output:

```
Data will be read ...
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Data will be set ...
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 12, 0, 13, 0, 14, 0, 15, 0]
```

I don't get an error ... but even not the result I expected. Test is using 32 elements of UInt32, but it looks like set_value() accesses something different?

Comment: What does "I can't access data for writing" mean? Do you get any error message? Also post a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can check your code and test it in their own

Comment: I added code snippet, output and description. Thanks so far!

Comment: How do you know the setter accesses something different? I.e. how did you checked those values were actually written and where?

Comment: My OPC UA server implementation includes a webserver displaying the value of r/w data. I also established a second client connection (UaExpert) in parallel showing identical result.

Comment: Had same issue. Solved updating to latest package version (0.98.12)